# Using ArcGIS Python API to consume standalone ArcGIS REST API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-python-api

I have access to a ArcGIS REST API service running on a standalone, unfederated ArcGIS Server. (Not AGOL or ArcGIS Enteprise) ie  (https://xxxx.xxxxx.com/arcgis/rest/services/xxxxxx/xxxxMap/MapServer)

Is there any way to consume the REST API services like MapServers, ImageServers using ArcGIS's Python API?

Also, I am working in a secured environment with no internet access. Using MapImageLayer from ArcGIS's Python API forces a GIS object as a parameter by default. And that GIS object calls out to [www.arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com) for anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get to the feature services in a standalone server by using the `arcgis.server.Server` class.

See the doc and tech article here:

- Python API (server submodule)
  https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.server.html#arcgis.gis.server.Server
- Access items ... standalone server
  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000021795

Here is a snippet to get access to a FeatureLayerCollection directly from the server instead of the portal.

```
from arcgis import *
from arcgis.gis import server

server_base_url = "https://servername.esri.com"
gis_server = server.Server(url=f"{server_base_url}/web_adaptor/admin",
                    token_url=f"{server_base_url}/web_adaptor/tokens/generateToken",
                    username="username",
                    password="pass.word")

content_dir = gis_server.content
service = content_dir.get("lsa_testing_feet")

print(type(service))

>>> <class 'arcgis.features.layer.FeatureLayerCollection'>
```